# uwp: changing titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor with ThemeResource

Tags: uwp

I want to make the `ForegroundColor` of the titlebar buttons dynamic if the User changes the AppTheme.

I'm created the app using the "Windows Template Studio" to get the settings for changing the `AppTheme`.

I declared following XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Color x:Key="CustomColor">#FF6D0839</Color>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeBaseLowColorBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemBaseLowColor}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeControlForegroundBaseHighBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeControlBackgroundBaseHighBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemBaseMediumLowColor}" />

<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <Color x:Key="SystemBaseMediumLowColor">Red</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <Color x:Key="SystemBaseMediumLowColor">Green</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        <Color x:Key="SystemBaseMediumLowColor">Blue</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in the code behind:

```
public static void SetRequestedTheme()
{
    if (Window.Current.Content is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        frameworkElement.RequestedTheme = Theme;

        ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;

        titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["SystemBaseMediumLowColor"];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the `titlebar.ButtonForegroundColor` remains the same. I'll always get the color of the light resource and not the color of the selected resource.
Any ideas?

P.S.: I also tried following with UWP.Toolkit

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp.SamplePages"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:extensions="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions"
  extensions:ApplicationView.Title="View Extensions"
  extensions:TitleBar.ButtonForegroundColor="White"
  extensions:StatusBar.BackgroundColor="{ThemeResource SystemBaseMediumLowColor}"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
```

Doing so, will throw an XAML excecption. When I use `StaticResource` instead it works?

Many thanks for your help

P.S.: I ended up like this:

```
    public static void SetRequestedTheme()
    {
        if (Window.Current.Content is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
        {
            frameworkElement.RequestedTheme = Theme;

            Color color;
            var appTheme = Application.Current.RequestedTheme;

            switch (Theme)
            {
                case ElementTheme.Default:
                    color = ((Color)Application.Current.Resources["SystemBaseHighColor"]);
                    break;
                case ElementTheme.Light:
                    if (appTheme == ApplicationTheme.Light) { color = ((Color)Application.Current.Resources["SystemBaseHighColor"]); }
                    else { color = ((Color)Application.Current.Resources["SystemAltHighColor"]); }
                    break;
                case ElementTheme.Dark:
                    if (appTheme == ApplicationTheme.Light) { color = ((Color)Application.Current.Resources["SystemAltHighColor"]); }
                    else { color = ((Color)Application.Current.Resources["SystemBaseHighColor"]); }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
            titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = color;
        }
    }
```

In the ApplicationTheme is stored the System setting of the user, which is activated by the "Default" ElementTheme

Depending on the ApplicatinTheme the result of ((Color)Application.Current.Resources["SystemBaseHighColor"]) is different, so I need to check an choose the right Resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can observe color and theme changes using the `UISettings` class in UWP. I have previously written a [blog post about](http://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/01/observing-system-color-changes-in-uwp-apps/) this. Simply said, you can observe the `UISettings.ColorValuesChanged` event to see when the colors or theme has changed and react to it. Also see this [nice helper class on GitHub](https://github.com/hawkerm/monaco-editor-uwp/blob/master/MonacoEditorComponent/Helpers/ThemeListener.cs), which also handles the Window activation (because the event will not be triggered when the app is in the background).

As for the reason `ThemeResource` setting for the UWP Community Toolkit extension does not work - as the color is set statically on the `TitleBar`, it has to be done via code, while `ThemeResource` is a XAML only markup extension, which means it is not compatible with this.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I ended up with this: